# Can I rotate cleats between left and right shoes?

Tags: cleat

If one foot's cleat wears quicker than the other due to riding style, is it a good idea to switch them after a certain time to extend the lifetime of the pair?

Comment: What style of cleats are they?

Comment: @jean-bernard Pellerin: You have asked a question which includes this question in its scope. It appears that you asked this one because you wanted a specific answer to the other one, which you did not recieve. Asking the same question in multiple ways is often seen as spam by other users, and results inyour questions recieving less attention than a single good question will. Please consider editing your first question to include this one more specifically.

Comment: @zenbike I was just trying to separate out different parts of the same problem. That way if anyone else is looking for a similar query online they will find it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see from your other question that they're Look Keos.

As they're plastic, they're going to wear quicker than a metal cleat, and yes, you could swap them around.

However, I think a better strategy might well be to replace them one at a time as they wear out.

Plastic stuff doesn't really like being repeatedly removed and reattached in most situations and you need to keep them in the correct positions.

Comment: Yep, I replace my right Look Keo cleat about twice as often as the left. Swapping around sounds like too much trouble for little gain.